# I'm looking for a TTS (text to speech) for ubuntu that is like Mac's short-key TTS option

Tags: sound, alternative, orca

I'm new to Ubuntu, and this is the only thing missing on my computer. I need something that doesn't require terminal used every time, and is mostly understandable. It doesn't have to be incredibly natural sounding. I have looked everywhere for something that is like Orca, but easier to control, and just a little bit more understandable.

I have speakit! on chrome, and that type of quality is more than good enough. I just have a lot of pdf's, ebooks, and word documents that I need to work too :(

Honestly, if Orca had a shortkey command that only read high-lighted text, I would be willing to settle with that.

Please help ubuntu community! You're my only hope!

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I encounter the exact same problem you are describing myself, one year ago, when switching from Mac to Ubuntu, and I created a new TTS utility which could replace the exact command.
It works offline, for free with AI-based high-quality voice. You can you it everywhere: Firefox browser, PDF reader, chrome, LibreOffice, etc.

Feel free to have a look, I just created a video tutorial with installation steps and DEMO: https://youtu.be/hb1ZVwUcPCU

Download link and Project page: https://github.com/MattePalte/Verbify-TTS

Feel free to leave comment/open issue to discuss new ideas, problems or constructive criticism.

Hoping it will help you.

Comment: +1 Sound nice :-) I have been happy with `espeak`. Maybe it is time for me to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there! The last step is MANUAL.
The following two commands are needed to call the Verbify-TTS service.

- COMMAND 1: READ THE TEXT (recommended key combination: ALT + ESC)
  The following is to ask the service to read the selected text:
  /home/cameron/Downloads/Verbify-TTS-main/env/bin/python /home/cameron/Downloads/Verbify-TTS-main/command_read.py
- COMMAND 2: STOP READING (recommended key combination: ALT + END)
  The following is to stop the current reading:
  /home/cameron/Downloads/Verbify-TTS-main/env/bin/python /home/cameron/Downloads/Verbify-TTS-main/command_stop.py

how do i get this step done? i am on ubuntu 23.04